# Is there anyway to transform a string to a field in a struct in C++/Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I have an struct like so:

```
typedef struct {
    int field1;
    int field2;
} Example;

Example data;
```

My real structure has about 20 fields. However I would like to assign values to those fields based on parsing a text file. Now, the obvious way of doing this is with a huge switch (or `if-else if` chain) testing on what attribute is being assigned. However this is bothersome and complicated to expand.

Is there any mechanism that would allow to transform a string lifted from a file to a struct field name? So for example if my file had a line `field1 = 23` I would know to assign `23` to the `data.field1` without the `switch`.

Comment: No there's not. The runtime has no idea of your variable names so it can't know on itself.

Comment: There's no way of doing this, but may be you can implement some sort of _chain of responsibility_ pattern to have a simple solution instead of a long if-else chain.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know what is chain of resposibility pattern. Could you elaborate?

Comment: It is like, whatever string you read from file, you pass it on to `filed1` (maybe a setter for `filed1`) and it checks the string, for whether the string is for itself, if it is, it assigns it to itself, if not, it passes on the string to next field's setter, maybe `filed2`'s, and `filed2`'s setter behaves the exact same way.

Comment: In this way, you won't have a long if-else chain, but instead each filed's setter will be responsible for setting the value to itself, or pass on to the next setter.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the suggestion! I like that approach. Maybe one of you could provide the answer so as to accept it? Make sure to leave it clear that it is not possible, since that is the actual answer to the question.

Comment: Why do you use `typedef struct` in C++?

Comment: I think it would be easier for you to use a serialized file, like JSON or XML so that you could parse and write it easily and with clean code, not with all those if-else statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write setters:

```
void setField1(const char *f) ;
void setField2(const char *f) ;
```

The setters are responsible to decode the string into an int.

Then you need an associative array (hash) that associates the field name to the function:

```
"field1" -> setField1
"field2" -> setField2
```

Then you need to grab the function pointer from the associative array and call it with the field as parameter. This is an example:

```
#include <iostream>

typedef struct {
  int field1;
  int field2;
} Example;

Example data;

void setField1(const char *f) {
  data.field1 = std::stoi(f); 
}

void setField2(const char *f) {
  data.field2 = std::stoi(f);
}

void (*tab[])(const char *) = { setField1, setField2 };

int main(void)
{
  data.field1 = 10 ;
  data.field2 = 20 ;
  tab[0]("43") ;
  tab[1]("12") ;
  std::cout << "fields:" << data.field1 << '|' << data.field2 << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Naturally you would need to do more than that to make a correct code. For one, Example should be a class and the setters moved there, then you need to decode the text line to get the indices, or to use an associative array.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use Qt's meta object system capabilities to call methods by name.

```
class SetFieldHelper : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SetFieldHelper(Example &data) : m_data(data) {}

    void setField(const QString &line) {
        QStringList parts = line.split('=');
        if (parts.count() == 2) {
            const QByteArray field = parts[0].trimmed().toUtf8();
            const QString value = parts[1].trimmed();

            QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, field.constData(), Q_ARG(QString, value));
        }
    }

private slots:
    void field1(const QString &value) {
        m_data.field1 = value.toInt();
    }

private:
    Example &m_data;
};
```

Comment: If I'm undertanding your example right, you would need a field function for each one of your fields, right? I think this is the best option, so far as I makes it easier to use Qt capabilities.

Comment: Yes, you would need one of these private slots for each field, each slot named with the field identifier used in the file.

Comment: If you use Qt's metadata, you might as well declare the properties themselves and access them directly. And it doesn't even need to be a `QObject`, then.

Comment: @KubaOber: I thought about that too, but wanted to keep it minimalistic. Also a QObject adapter allows to take the item to modify by reference or pointer and avoid coping.

Comment: No copying needed. Ever.

Comment: Yes, assuming that either the type declaration can be changed or casting to a gadget type with compatible memory layout.

Answer (score 2):

There is a neat way to do that using the old technique called [X Macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro).

Here is an example:

```
struct A
{
    #define STRUCT_A_MEMBER_LIST \
        X(foo) \
        X(bar)

    #define X(name) int name;
    STRUCT_A_MEMBER_LIST
    #undef X

    void SetFieldByName(const char *field_name, int value)
    {
        #define X(name) if (!std::strcmp(field_name, #name)) name = std::atoi(value); else
        STRUCT_A_MEMBER_LIST return;
        #undef X
    }

    #undef STRUCT_A_MEMBER_LIST
}
```

It's possible to replace if-else-if chain with a hash map or something else, but either way you won't need to specify field names manually.

Comment: This is great. Thanks!

Comment: I guess you meant to do `std::strcmp(field_name, #name)`?

Comment: @Mike Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage the Qt's metaobject system via `Q_GADGET`. This has the following advantages:

1. No need to add getters/setters - they can be used if available, but Qt can access the members of primitive or Qt types directly.
2. No need to deal with conversion of the strings to target types. The meta-property system does the necessary conversions automatically for you.
3. The metadata has no overhead - it doesn't add any data to the target type, because the target type remains unchanged.

   Even then, `Q_PROPERTY` is an empty macro, and `Q_GADGET` adds a static method to the class.

If you ask me, that's a pretty good leverage :)

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/struct-deserialize-39547524
#include <QtCore>
#include <string>

// Original API

struct Example1 {
    int field1;
    double field2;
    bool field3;
    std::string field4;
};

// Type-Specific Adapter API

template <typename T> struct GadgetTraits;

struct Example1Gadget : Example1 {
    Q_GADGET
    Q_PROPERTY(int field1 MEMBER field1)
    Q_PROPERTY(double field2 MEMBER field2)
    Q_PROPERTY(bool field3 MEMBER field3)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString field4 READ getField4 WRITE setField4)
public:
    void setField4(const QString & val) { field4 = val.toStdString(); }
    QString getField4() const { return QString::fromStdString(field4); }
};
template <> struct GadgetTraits<Example1> { using gadget_type = Example1Gadget; };

// Generic Adapter API

template <typename T>
void set(T & gadget, const QStringList & data)
{
    for (auto & entry : data) set(gadget, entry);
}

template <typename T>
void set(T & gadget, const QString & data)
{
    const QMetaObject & mo = GadgetTraits<T>::gadget_type::staticMetaObject;
    auto const fields = data.split('=');
    if (fields.length() != 2) return;
    auto field = fields[0].trimmed();
    auto value = fields[1].trimmed();
    auto i = mo.indexOfProperty(field.toUtf8());
    if (i < 0) return;
    auto prop = mo.property(i);
    prop.writeOnGadget(&gadget, value);
}

int main() {
    Example1 ex;
    set(ex, {"field1 = 3", "field2 = 1.5", "field3 = true", "field4 = foo bar"});
    Q_ASSERT(ex.field1 == 3);
    Q_ASSERT(ex.field2 == 1.5);
    Q_ASSERT(ex.field3 == true);
    Q_ASSERT(ex.field4 == "foo bar");
}
#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Well, I guess one could derive the gadget adapter from the actual data type and then cast to the adapter to avoid the copying

Comment: Even better: use traits and there's no need to cast anything :)

Comment: Ah, nice edit, almost like the prototype approach from QtScript times.